# Java Swing Dice Rolling Animation

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm coding up a GUI game of craps. There is a JButton called "roll" which when clicked rolls the dice for the game. The GUI then displays what you rolled using jpeg's of die faces.

Everything works great, except I'm supposed to now add an animation to the GUI. My idea was to somehow rapidly display different face values for a short period of time (simulating a "roll") using the same method of displaying the jpeg's. However, as I'm sure you all know, that doesn't work.

I'm familiar with the idea of EDT and the Timer class, but I'm not sure exactly how to use them. Basically I want this animation to happen when I hit the "roll" button, and when the animation is finished, I want it to display what was actually rolled like it did before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code I have thus far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


/* This is the GUI declaration */
public class NCrapsGUI extends JFrame {
     //code...   
/* Action when "roll" is clicked */
    private void rollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
        game.rollDice();
            //Rolls both die
            sumOfDice.setText(Integer.toString(game.getSum()));
            //Displays the sum of the die
            numRolls.setText(Integer.toString(game.getNumRolls()));
            //Displays the number of rolls in each game
            // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Die JPEG's">
            // If statements display the die face based on the number rolled
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 1) {
                 die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face1.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 2) {
                die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face2.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 3) {
                die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face3.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 4) {
                die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face4.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 5) {
                die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face5.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie1Value() == 6) {
                die1Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face6.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 1) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face1.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 2) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face2.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 3) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face3.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 4) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face4.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 5) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face5.jpg")));
            }
            if (game.getDie2Value() == 6) {
                die2Disp.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/face6.jpg")));
            }
            //</editor-fold>
            /* 
             * If the game is beyond the first roll, it checks to see if the sum of the
             * values rolled equal 7 or the point value for a loss or win respectively.
             * If it is a win, it adds a win. Likewise for a loss.
             */
            if (game.getGameStatus() == 2) {
                if (game.getSum() == game.getPoint()) {
                    game.addWin();
                    numWins.setText(Integer.toString(game.getWins()));
                    game.setGameStatus(1);
                    game.setPoint(0);
                    game.resetRolls();
                    return;
                }
                if (game.getSum() == 7) {
                    game.addLoss();
                    numLosses.setText(Integer.toString(game.getLosses()));
                    game.setGameStatus(1);
                    game.setPoint(0);
                    game.resetRolls();
                    return;
                }
            }

            /*
             * This checks to see if the game is on the first roll. If it is, it checks 
             * if the sum of the die is 7 or 11 for a win, or 2, 3, or 12 for a loss. If
             * not, it passes it on to the next roll and sets the point value to the sum
             */
            if (game.getGameStatus() == 1) {
                game.setPoint(game.getSum());
                dieSum.setText(Integer.toString(game.getPoint()));

                if (((game.getSum() == 7) || ((game.getSum() == 11)))) {
                    game.addWin();
                    numWins.setText(Integer.toString(game.getWins()));
                    game.setPoint(0);
                    dieSum.setText(Integer.toString(game.getPoint()));
                    game.resetRolls();
                    return;
                }

                if (((game.getSum() == 2) || ((game.getSum()) == 3)) || (game.getSum()) == 12) {
                    game.addLoss();
                    numLosses.setText(Integer.toString(game.getLosses()));
                    game.setPoint(0);
                    dieSum.setText(Integer.toString(game.getPoint()));
                    game.resetRolls();
                    return;
                } else {
                    game.setGameStatus(2);
                }
            }
       }
```

EDIT WITH UPDATED CODE!!!

Here's where the Timer and array are declared:

```
public class NCrapsGUI extends JFrame
{
private Timer timer; 
private int numPlayers;
private int totalIcons = 6;

private ImageIcon imageArray[];`

/* CODE */
```

And here is where the array is populated inside the NCrapsGUI constructor:

```
imageArray = new ImageIcon[totalIcons];
   for (int i = 0; i < 6 ;i++)
    {
        int temp = i + 1;
        imageArray[i] = new ImageIcon("face" + temp + ".jpg");
    }

    initComponents();`
```

This is the entire rollActionPerformed method. I'm guessing the Timer gets started right
at the beginning, but whenever I try to start it I get loads of error. However, when I
I made a new JPanel seperately, and made it implement action listener, I got no
errors. I tried adding implements ActionListner to this declaration, but NetBeans literally
would not let me type anything in.

```
private void rollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     



game.rollDice();
//Rolls both die

sumOfDice.setText(Integer.toString(game.getSum()));
//Displays the sum of the die

numRolls.setText(Integer.toString(game.getNumRolls()));
//Displays the number of rolls in each game

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Die JPEG's">
// If statements display the die face based on the number rolled
if (game.getDie1Value() == 1) 
{
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[0]);
}

if (game.getDie1Value() == 2) 
{
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[1]);
}

if (game.getDie1Value() == 3)
{
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[2]);
}

if (game.getDie1Value() == 4) {
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[3]);
}

if (game.getDie1Value() == 5) {
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[4]);
}

if (game.getDie1Value() == 6) 
{
    die1Disp.setIcon(imageArray[5]);
}

if (game.getDie2Value() == 1) 
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[0]);
}

if (game.getDie2Value() == 2) 
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[1]);
}


if (game.getDie2Value() == 3) 
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[2]);
}

if (game.getDie2Value() == 4)
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[3]);
}

if (game.getDie2Value() == 5) 
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[4]);
}

if (game.getDie2Value() == 6) 
{
    die2Disp.setIcon(imageArray[5]);
}

//</editor-fold>

/* 
 * If the game is beyond the first roll, it checks to see if the sum of the
 * values rolled equal 7 or the point value for a loss or win respectively.
 * If it is a win, it adds a win. Likewise for a loss.
 */

if (game.getGameStatus() == 2) {
    if (game.getSum() == game.getPoint()) {
        game.addWin();
        numWins.setText(Integer.toString(game.getWins()));
        game.setGameStatus(1);
        game.setPoint(0);
        game.resetRolls();
        return;
    }

    if (game.getSum() == 7) {
        game.addLoss();
        numLosses.setText(Integer.toString(game.getLosses()));
        game.setGameStatus(1);
        game.setPoint(0);
        game.resetRolls();
        return;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Not sure who down-voted you or why (a drive-by down-vote), but I up-voted you to counteract it.

Comment: for posting http://sscce.org/ +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic idea behind the animation is a good one I think, but whether it works or not is all in the implementation details of course. I suggest

- That you read in your images and make ImageIcons once, probably at the start of the program.
- That you put the icons into an ImageIcon array with a length of 7 -- but you'll put an icon into the 1-6 slots, leaving the 0th item null.
- That you use a Swing Timer to swap these icons randomly with some appropriate delay, say 200 or 300 msec.
- That you use a a Random object to get a random number between 1 and 6, and then with this number as your array index, get the Icon out of the array.
- That you display the ImageIcons in a JLabel (or two JLabels if you're displaying 2 die) and swap Icons by simply calling the JLabel's `setIcon(...)` method.

**Edit**
You state in your comment that you tried:

```
timer = new Timer(100,this);
```

And that's your problem -- your use of `this`. You shouldn't try to use the same ActionListner for everything. Instead create an ActionListener right there, where you need it.  Something like,

```
  timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvt) {
        // ... put your ActionListener's code here 
     }
  });
```

Comment: +1 advice. I'd also look at solving the problem of rendering a single die, first.

Comment: Do I put all this code in my rollActionPerformed method? Aside from populating the array.

Comment: You will create your ImageIcons in a constructor. The rollActionPerformed will likely be started by a button and will start the Timer which will have its own ActionListener, and there is where you swap icons randomly until it repeats x amount of times (you'll give it an int counter variable that you increment and check).

Comment: Alright. I have the array down pat. However, whenever I try to start the Timer in "rollActionPerformed", I get an error. Does this mean I need to have rollActionPerformed implement ActionListener? I created my GUI using the Swing interface in NetBeans, and it won't let me manually edit the declaration.

Comment: @SkankinJake: I think we'll need to see some (or all) of your latest code to figure this out. Best if you could create an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was trying to use Timer right inside the rollActionPerformed method. Right before game.rollDice(). I used `timer = new Timer(100,this)` but the compiler wasn't having it.

Comment: So does that ActionListener declaration encompass my rollActionPerformed code, or just my animation? And thank you for being so patient with me.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work! I put the animation in the Timer declaration you provided, inside the rollActionPerformed method. How do I get it to stop animation though? Just timer.stop()?

Comment: @SkankinJake: Regarding `timer.stop()` -- Try it, you'll see what it does.

Comment: I've been fiddling around with it for a bit. Now I just have to figure out how to stop the thread after a couple seconds have elapsed. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @SkankinJake: I've used a counter variable that is held by the ActionListener and that increments in the actionPerformed method. Once it reaches a set value, I call `stop()` on the Timer.

Comment: That's what I tried at first, and couldn't get it to work. Then I moved the conditional statement inside the actionListener and now it works. I think I'm all set now!